# Rewrite for owncloud shorty - from a different server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a little problem...

I have 2 Servers - one ist for my Cloud service - one for the rest.

On my cloud server I have owncloud running with shory the URL shorter, and my 2nd server should rewrite my main url to the long url from my 2nd server.

cloudserver:

cloud.domain.com

my URL for the shorty service is:
https://cloud.domain.com/public.php?service=shorty_relay&id=1LaE0eztba

webserver:

apache shoud accept the requests for domain.com - also domain.com/go/[VAR OF SHORTER]

So when I open domain.com/go/1LaE0eztba
my Apache shoud "kind of redirekt" to https://cloud.domain.com/public.php?service=shorty_relay&id=1LaE0eztba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using a single redirection rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/go/([A-Za-z0-9]{4,12}) http://cloud.domain.com/public.php?service=shorty_relay&id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is mentioned in the documentation for Shortys 'Static Backend'.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I had to remove the first slash in the matching part for this to work: `RewriteRule ^go/([A-Za-z0-9]{4,12}) .....`
`

Comment: Then most likely you are rewriting inside a `.htaccess` style file, I assume? That is fine, however note that this is much slower than using the central apache configuration, much more error prone and harder to debug. However sometimes there is no alternative. Glad you sorted it out, though!.